# Unable to resize Win partition under Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt, mbr

I know my problem sounds pretty common but all advices I found on the internet did not worked for me.

I try to resize partition and I cant lower its size.My previous SSD disk failed and I need to install system on my second HDD disk. HDD was previously formated on win7. I could create new partition instead of old but obviously I want to keep my data untouched. During Ubuntu installation proccess partition manager says its unallocated space but its normally booting to view folders and stuff.

I experience error like:

[image: GPT Signatures error]

In this case /dev/sdb/ is linux pendrive but I think it might be related to /dev/sda/ - HDD. I tried to fix this with doing:

- Changing Boot mode from UEFI to normal mode.
- Using gparted (error above) with result red exclamation mark near disk.
- Using fixparts on my HDD (/dev/sda/) with result:

> Loading MBR data from /dev/sda
>
> This disk appears to be a GPT disk. Use GNU Parted or GPT fdisk on it!
>
> Exiting!'

- Using testdisk which wrote MBR to partition (on /dev/sda/)
- Using gdisk on /dev/sda/ with commands: x then p then w. Gdisk told its valid GPT table.
- Tried to change in my UEFI storage setting AHCI to IDE.

I know my approach is chaotic, as I just try different internet solutions. Maybe there is something wrong in order of things I did.

Comment: Windows partitions should be resized from within Windows.  Ubuntu does not handle some aspects of NTFS well.  You may be much better off using the live CD/USB to copy data from the hard drive to a storage device (such as a USB hard disk) and creating new partitions.

Comment: I agree with Charles; do it from Windows. Do *NOT,* though, create new partitions in Windows! The Windows disk partitioner  can seriously mess that up. Also, the GParted message about `/dev/sdb` is harmless; ignore it. Some of what you did, such as using TestDisk, is potentially dangerous. Switching the storage type (AHCI to IDE or vice-versa) can render Windows unbootable, but this is easily reversed. If you keep trying things randomly, you *will* make matters worse, and in a way that might not be so easy to repair!

Comment: Choose "No" to be shown GParted. The error message exclusively is about `/dev/sdb`. This happens when there is no valid partition table on your usb stick, which can be perfectly fine and happens if you simply `dd` the image onto the usb stick.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Can you transform this to answer? It seems to be valid solution I will accept this.People who found this post should know not to waste time to find extra solutions.

Comment: @amonowy Should be an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows partitions should be resized from within Windows; Ubuntu does not handle some aspects of NTFS well.

You may be much better off using the live CD/USB to copy data from the hard drive to a storage device (such as a USB hard disk) and creating new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue with any other experimental changes, you should make a complete backup of your Windows Installation.